# Unitary transformation of Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Dirac equation is given by $$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi=0.$$ The matrices $\gamma^\mu$ satisfy the relation $$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=\gamma^\mu\gamma^n+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2g^{\mu\nu},$$ where
$g^{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric.

I read from Ryder's QFT textbook (pg 43) that for a $4\times 4$ unitary matrix $S$,

1. $\gamma'^\mu=S\gamma^\mu S^{-1}$ also satisfy the the relation $\{\gamma'^\mu,\gamma'^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$.
2. $\psi'=S\psi$ also satisfies the Dirac equation if the matrices are transformed using  $\gamma'^\mu=S\gamma^\mu S^{-1}$.

How can it be shown that the above two statements are true?

Here are my attempts to prove these two statements:

1. $\{\gamma'^\mu,\gamma'^\nu\}=\gamma'^\mu\gamma'^\nu+\gamma'^\nu\gamma'^\mu
       = S\gamma^\mu S^{-1}S\gamma^\nu S^{-1} + S\gamma^\nu S^{-1}S\gamma^\mu S^{-1} =S\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu S^{-1} +
       S\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu
       S^{-1}=S\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}S^{-1}=2Sg^{\mu\nu}S^{-1}$
2. I don't know how to show this. It seems like the author is doing
   something like a coordinate transformation using the unitary matrix
   $S$. How does $\partial_\mu$ transform in this case?

Comment: Derivatives  transform opposite way as the gammas. This is why have different (covariant <-> contravariant) indices. So simply substitute them into the equation.

Comment: Is he really considering general unitary S? Because then the metric has to transform too (perhaps a typo... He may have missed the prime over g?)

Comment: @daydreamer Maybe the minkowski metric is a constant in all inertial frames? I'm not sure. He did not say what transformation $S$ represents...

Comment: @RobertSzili What do u mean exactly by opposite? The gamma transform as $S\gamma S^{-1}$. You mean $\partial_\mu$ transform as $S^{-1}\partial_\mu S$? Also why does the gamma transform like this?

Comment: TaeNyFan: 1.: exactly. 2.: because the derivations transform in the opposite way ;) . All is about the Lorentz invariance. Like if you redefine meter to be twice as big, the measurement values will be halved. The physical sizes remain the same.

Comment: Minkowski won't change under Poincaré transformations. That's not as near as to say general unitary transformations

Comment: The $\gamma^{\mu}$ are matrices, whereas $\partial_\mu$ and $g^{\mu\nu}$ are not. In the Clifford-algebra relation the identity matrix  $\mathbf{1}$ on the right side was forgotten: $\gamma^{mu}\gamma^{\nu}+ \gamma^{nu}\gamma^{\mu} = 2g^{\mu\nu}\cdot \mathbf{1}$. And $S^{-1}\mathbf{1}S = \mathbf{1}$. This is how it works. For the rest, it written in all books on QFT.

Comment: To make it a little clearer: Even though gammas are matrices, they have one Lorentz index (greek) and two matrix indices (not visible). The matrix indices interact only with the other gammas' matrix indices and the state vector.